# Template Functions Defined in Source File

Tags: c++

I've seen all of the other posts on stack overflow with this exact question, but I'd like to know if it's changed in C++17/slightly earlier (maybe with the extern keyword)

Here's the scenario, for those unfamiliar:

```
/// Foo.hpp
namespace Foo
{
    class CFoo
    {
    public:
        template< typename T > T fnFoo( T );
    };

    int fnFooInt( int );
}

/// Foo.cpp
template< typename T > T Foo::CFoo::fnFoo( T x ) // doesn't work
{
    return x;
}

int fnFooInt( int iFoo ) // works
{
    return iFoo;
}
```

One solution was to declare what templates were used (which sort of defeats the purpose for templates). Another is as follows:

```
/// Bar.hpp
namespace Bar
{
    class CBar
    {
    public:
        template< typename T > T fnBar( T );
    };

    int fnBarInt( int );
}

/// Bar.tpp
template< typename T > T Bar::CBar::fnBar( T x ) // works
{
    return x;
}

/// Bar.cpp
int fnBarInt( int iBar ) // works
{
    return iBar;
}
```

Comment: extern templates have been dropped as they were unworkable. As before, you need a definition of the template function in the compilation unit that calls it.

Comment: @RichardHodges - I think you mean `export`-ed templates. `extern` templates (well, specific extern instantiations) are very much in.